# Problems select mysqli

Tags: php

I am trying to make a select to my table 'detail' where I have 4 registers with id 0,1,2,3 but this only returns the ids 1,2,3. What will be?

```
$sqls = "
SELECT *
FROM details 
WHERE ped = 4500088849";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqls);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
print $row['ebelp'];
}
```

My table
[image]

Comment: Please include your complete database table. Without this data it's really hard to help you.

Comment: @csabinho check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is filtering for rows where the column `ped` contains the value 11.

Using the mysql command line perform the query

```
SELECT ped, ebelp FROM details;
```

And review the value in the `ped` column for register 0, it sounds like it has a value other then 11.

Using the query `SELECT * FROM details` will get you all rows with all columns from the details table.

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause from your query do you get all rows returned?

Can you provide the table definition (using mysql command line: `desc details;`)